# Node.js fs.createWriteStream undefined function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write data to a text file in Node.js. When initializing the write stream I get the following error message:[image]

Comment: Have you defined fs? can you paste your entire code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure you have included at the top of your node program

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Also It looks like you spelled 'Stream' incorrectly

```
fs.createWriteSteam > fs.createWriteStream
```

Comment: Silly me. Mispelling, I checked for mispelling before I posted but I guess I missed it.

Comment: No worries, do it all the time. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that may come up is trying to get createWriteStream from 'fs/promises'.
It doesn't exist on 'fs/promises'. (At least on NodeJS version 14);

My solution was to import both:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fsPromises = require('fs/promises');
```

Comment: The question has already been answered, and also this is the incorrect solution. - Review